# How to set an Access Tab Control's page name by VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form in MS Access with a Tab Control (called `TabCtrl`). This control has several pages, each with a subform.

On `Form_Open`, I want to query the subforms for the total number of records and put that number in the tab's name. For example, the tab named *MyTab* should become *MyTab (2)*:

```
Private Sub SetTabName_MyTab()
    Dim i As Integer
    i = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select count(*) from [MyQry];").Fields(0).Value
    TabCtrl.Pages("MyTab").Name = "MyTab (" & i & ")"
End Sub
```

However, when I run this, the last line returns **Run-time error 2136 "To set this property, open the form or report in Design view"**.  Does this mean I can't do this in code? Should I use another Event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to change the `internal` name of the control, rather than `caption` on the tab page control.

Try:

```
ATabcontrol.Pages("MyTab").Caption = "MyTab(" & i & ")"
```

> Note: I have done this before and found issues with the text not changing till the tabcontrol was manipulated.

Comment: Bingo! I gave up on this detail long ago.  I tested this on the Form's Open event and don't see any problems so far.

Comment: Anyone know how to tweak this code so it runs from within the subform?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Dim s as string

'To Get current Tab Caption
s = Me.TabCtl.Pages(Me.TabCtl.Value).Caption

'To Set current Tab Caption
s = "TabName"

Me.TabCtl.Pages(Me.TabCtl.Value).Caption = s
```